# C# -- Issue with arrays. Not reading user input

Tags: c#, arrays

So i'm trying to make a console program that takes 10 numbers from the user and adds them then averages the sum. Within the do while loop the program is supposed to keep asking for the next number.

```
{
        Console.WriteLine("Hey there! If you could go ahead and just give me like 10 numbers, that'd be great... And I'll tell you what, if you do, I'll add them up and average them all up for ya.");

        // declare an array of strings
        int[] aryNumbers;
        int intSum = 0;
        int intAverage = 0;

        // initialize the array
        aryNumbers = new int[10];

        aryNumbers[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[2] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[3] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[4] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[5] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[6] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[7] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[8] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        aryNumbers[9] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Okay, give me a number.");
            aryNumbers[] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        } while (intSum != 0);


        int intNumbers = aryNumbers.Length;
        //for loop to average sum of array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < intNumbers; i++) 
        {
            intSum += aryNumbers[i];
        }

        intAverage = intSum / intNumbers;
        Console.WriteLine("You're average comes out to... " + intAverage);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I really have no clue what to do, i'm very new to this

Thanks

Comment: Does this code even compile correctly?  Some of the code inside your do/while loop looks suspicious.  (Also, is this homework/educational?)

Comment: no, sorry. It's not compiling correctly. The error says "Identifier expected" inside the do while loop at the equals sign. and yes it is for a class. I'm not necessarily looking for the answer, but just some help getting on the right path.

Comment: That's a good hint--you should review the syntax for accessing the elements in an array. You must provide an explicit index when doing so.

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your code. I think you should read a whole chapter on arrays. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)'s a tutorial on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Unfortunately, we don't have a textbook for the class, and if we don't take perfect notes, we're screwed. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1207424: Google's my textbook!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
        using System.Linq;

        .....

        Console.WriteLine("Hey there! If you could go ahead and just give me like 10 numbers, that'd be great... And I'll tell you what, if you do, I'll add them up and average them all up for ya.");
        // declare the array
        int[] aryNumbers = new int[10];

        for(int i =0; i<aryNumbers.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Okay, give me a number.");
            aryNumbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        int intAverage = (int)aryNumbers.Average();
        Console.WriteLine("You're average comes out to... " + intAverage);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: We try not to just give people the answer here, especially when it's homework.  Presumably (hopefully?) the OP wants to learn how to do this himself or herself, not just do the assignment.

Comment: +1 for using LINQ well.  However, two style criticisms that also apply to the poster's code sample: there is no need for the obvious comment "declare the array," and if you're going to use Hungarian, use the standard "rg" prefix for an array rather than "ary."

Comment: <twocents>If this question was for educational/homework purposes, just providing a completed solution might not be terribly helpful.</twocents>

Comment: ...and seriously, Hungarian notation isn't needed for C#. Intellisense and tooltips in VS are good enough to make it unnecessary (and burdensome).

Comment: Could someone explain what exactly this does                           "for (int i = 0; i < aryNumbers.Length; i++)" I know the elements its composed of but what is it that aryNumbers.Length; does?

Comment: @user1207424 Array.Length.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx. I used aryNumbers.Length instead of 10 is to minimize the places using magic number.